# how can I write to dfs share with different users other than mount user on the linux server

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, cifs, dfs

I want to write dfs share with active directory groups on the Linux server. I mounted CIFS with ad user who is in the same active directory group. When I write to the directory with other than mount user I got the permission error. I have changed the permissions for both windows and Linux servers. I added ad groups to dfs share directory on the windows side and chmod 777 Linux side. How can I write ad users other than mount users to dfs share directory on the Linux server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Linux `cifs` mounts only use a single SMB user account for all local UIDs. You can mount the share with `-o file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777` to grant full access to all local UIDs, but they will all share the same AD account that you used when mounting.

To have each local UID automatically use *its own* AD account, you'll need the `-o multiuser` option instead. Note that Linux won't be able to prompt for credentials on access, so this works best if you use Kerberos authentication (`-o sec=krb5`, and have each user use SSSD or kinit to obtain the Kerberos credentials from AD).

Multiuser mode *can* work with password-based NTLM, each user still needs to pre-set their credentials using `cifscreds add`, but as this relies on kernel keyrings (the cifs driver code unfortunately insists on per-session keyrings and doesn't accept the per-uid keyring) it is actually more difficult to deal with than the Kerberos mode.